# Scroll into a certain div that is hidden in the beggining

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, next.js

Im building a web chat app in next.js and i have a emoji picker button that when its clicked the menu of emojis appear.The thing is that in order to the user sees the menu of the emojis he has to scroll down.I have tried scrollIntoView() but it doesnt seem to work,possibly im doing something wrong.

```
 <EmoticonContainer >
        
    {showEmojis && (<Picker id="picker" style={{width: '100%'}} onSelect={addEmoji}/>)}
        
</EmoticonContainer>
<InputContainer id="container"  >
    <IconButton onClick={() => {setShowEmojis(!showEmojis),()=>document.getElementById('picker').scrollIntoView(true)}}>
        <EmojiEmotionsIcon style={{ color: 'purple' }} fontSize='inherit' />
    </IconButton>
    <Input style={{fontFamily:"Roboto",fontSize:"12px"}} onKeyUp={()=>ChangeSendIcon()} onKeyPress={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault(); }} value={input} onChange={e=> setInput(e.target.value)}/>

    <div>
        <IconButton id="send" onClick={sendMessage} style={{ color: 'purple',display:'none' }} disabled={!input} type="submit">
            <SendIcon></SendIcon>
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton style={{ color: 'purple'}} id="record" onMouseUp={()=>record()}>
           <MicIcon ></MicIcon> 
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton style={{ color: 'purple',display:"none" }} onClick={()=>stop()} id="stop" >
           <StopIcon></StopIcon> 
        </IconButton>
    </div>

    
    
</InputContainer>
```

I have tried this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(showEmojis) {
 document.getElementById('picker').scrollIntoView(true)
 }
} , [showEmojis])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `document.getElementById('picker').scrollIntoView(true)` use the `React.useRef()` hook.

E.g. at the start of your function

```
const pickerRef = useRef()
```

then in your useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(showEmojis) {
     pickerRef.current.scrollIntoView(true)
 }
} , [showEmojis])
```

then in your return body

```
<Picker ref={pickerRef} id="picker" style={{width: '100%'}} onSelect={addEmoji}/>
```

It's not advised to use javascript query in jsx.

Comment: Throws this error-TypeError: pickerRef.current.scrollIntoView is not a function